# ios database locked error on update query

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite, locked

I am trying to update SQLite table but getting following error. Following is my code.

I have closed the database connection as suggested in earlier threads but getting the same error. Any help would be appreciated

```
-(bool)updateRecord:(NSString *)strRowID :(NSString *)strFilePath :(NSString *)strStatus
{
    sqlite3 *objsqlite3temp;
    const char *dbpath = [DATABASE_PATH UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &objsqlite3temp) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *updatetSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE files set status='%@', path='%@' WHERE id = %@", strStatus,strFilePath,strRowID];
        const char *insert_stmt = [updatetSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(objsqlite3temp, insert_stmt, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {

                //  NSLog(@"Entered and return");
             sqlite3_close(objsqlite3temp);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error message %s",sqlite3_errmsg(objsqlite3temp));
        }

        //ADD THIS LINE TO YOUR CODE
        sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
    }
    else
    {
        sqlite3_close(objsqlite3temp); //Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to release all the memory.
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: it is because you may have some connection open to the database somewhere, and you are opening another connection by calling the update method. CLose the previous one and open the new one!!!

Comment: look into the project and search for sqlite3_open....and make sure every sqlite3_open have a close at the end!!!!